# Number of points in an intersecting linear hypergraph

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, hypergraphs

An *intersecting linear hypergraph* is a pair $H=(P,\mathcal{L})$ where $P\neq\emptyset$ is a finite set and $\mathcal{L}$ is a collection of subsets of $P$ such that

- every member of $\mathcal{L}$ has at least 2 elements, and
- if $l_1, l_2 \in \mathcal{L}$ then there is $p\in P$ such that $l_1 \cap l_2 = \{p\}$.

I am convinced that in any intersecting linear hypergraph $H=(P,\mathcal{L})$ we have at least as many points as lines (i.e. $|P| \geq |\mathcal{L}|$). How can this be proved (if it is correct at all)? And if it is correct, does $|P| \geq |\mathcal{L}|$ also hold if $P$ is infinite?

Comment: I think this question deserves more attention.  After giving it a try I'm convinced that $|P| \geq |\mathcal{L}|$ just like you (but can't prove it).  Have you tried posting this on mathoverflow ?  Or maybe people are scared by the title of the question (I was at first, because I didn't know what an intersecting linear hypergraph" was).  Perhaps changing it to "number of vertices in a hypergraph with each pair of edges sharing exactly one vertex" would attract more people...or maybe not, I don't know :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I just put the question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180334/number-of-points-in-an-intersecting-linear-hypergraph

Comment: Heh, I just saw the answer.  They make it sound so easy :)